# What is the difference between (function(global){}(this), constructor functions, and classes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

There are three ways I currently know how to make classes and objects.

Method 1 (This scary thing):

```
;(function(global) {
  let module = global.player1 = {};
  module.x = 0;
  module.y = 0;
  module.tick = function() { /* Do stuff */ }
  module.show = function(g) {
    g.fillRect(module.x, module.y, 16, 16);
  }
})(this);
```

Method 2 (Classes ES6):

```
class CPlayer {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 16;
    this.y = 0;
  }
}
CPlayer.prototype.tick = function() { /* Do stuff */ }
CPlayer.prototype.show = function(g) {
    g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 16, 16);  
}
let player2 = new CPlayer();
```

Method 3 (Constructor Function):

```
function FPlayer() {
  this.x = 32;
  this.y = 0;
}
FPlayer.prototype.tick = function() { /* Do stuff */ }
FPlayer.prototype.show = function(g) {
  g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 16, 16);  
}
let player3 = new FPlayer();
```

What is the difference between the three, and which one is most efficient/practical? Especially with the first method?

Comment: The first one is not making a class, it's making a **module**.

Comment: This question is too broad and highly opinionated, making it ill-suited for StackOverflow. It'd probably be a good question for the Code Review Stack Exchange though. If you have highly-focused, specific questions, those are good for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods 1 is not a class, nor an object, but is rather a module - this method allows you to encapsulate some code inside of a function which is immediately executed in the current execution environment.  Since you are passing in `this` at the time you call it, whatever your current scope is its context (and this could be called from *within* a class declaration, for example, as a kind of mixin.

Method 2 is newly available in ES6 as mentioned in your question.  Some developers frown on this because of the confusion it causes however.  See for example here: https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/is-class-in-es6-the-new-bad-part-6c4e6fe1ee65.  The basic advantage of this is that it affords us some syntactic sugar, while the downside is that it makes it seem like JavaScript *actually* has classes, which it does not (and again as mentioned in your question itself, it relies on prototyping for inheritance).

Method 3 is the "classic" way to create an object.  Relying on the way that JavaScript scopes, closures and context work, we arrive at a function that can be called as if it were a class constructor, and it indeed does a pretty good job of approximating this.  Personally, this is still my preferred method - there is no real difference in efficiency among the three methods listed, but this method is the oldest and therefore the most widespread and *readable*.  For that reason, it gets my vote.

Comment: What would the use for modules be then?

Comment: Modules are useful in several ways: they create a "private" scope for certain variables and only expose an API that ensures these are handled properly, and we are also shielded from possible naming conflicts.  Modules and classes are closely related, but you should prefer classes in a case where you need an actual object to represent something (and especially if you need more than one).  A module would be more useful in a case where you are providing a feature set and want to hide some of the implementation.