# Can You Implement Javascript Class Via Function Expression?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, function-expression

I was tackling this question in leet code:

> Implement the MapSum class:
>
> MapSum() Initializes the MapSum object. void insert(String key, int
> val) Inserts the key-val pair into the map. If the key already
> existed, the original key-value pair will be overridden to the new
> one. int sum(string prefix) Returns the sum of all the pairs' value
> whose key starts with the prefix.

In javascript, the template for solving the question is:

```
/**
 * Initialize your data structure here.
 */
var MapSum = function() {

};

/** 
 * @param {string} key 
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {void}
 */
MapSum.prototype.insert = function(key, val) {

};

/** 
 * @param {string} prefix
 * @return {number}
 */
MapSum.prototype.sum = function(prefix) {

};

/** 
 * Your MapSum object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * var obj = new MapSum()
 * obj.insert(key,val)
 * var param_2 = obj.sum(prefix)
 */
```

I was struck by the class template. I'm used to seeing javascript classes more similar to this:

```
class MapSum {
  constructor() {

  }

  insert(key, value) {

  }

  sum(prefix) {

  }
}
```

**Is the template leetcode provided, considered a class? What kind of class is it? What is it called when you initialize an object via function expression** (`var MapSum = function() { //....}`) ? **What are the biggest differences/implications from writing a class that way vs the way I suggested?**

Comment: The `class` syntax is relatively new to JavaScript. It does basically (not exactly) what a constructor function and prototype initialization does.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp / https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between (function(global){}(this), constructor functions, and classes in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540155/what-is-the-difference-between-functionglobalthis-constructor-functions)

Comment: This tutorial looks obsolete (apart from prototypes, they're using `var` and seem not to be aware of the built-in `Map`). Just find another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class` keyword is actually just syntaxic sugar over [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

This code demonstrates that the two syntaxes are equivalent:

```js
class MapSum {
  constructor() {
    
  }
    
  insert(key, value) {
    
  }
    
  sum(prefix) {
    
  }
}

console.log(typeof MapSum); // function (actually the constructor)
console.log(MapSum.prototype.insert); // function
console.log(MapSum.prototype.sum); // function
```

A class is actually just a constructor `function`, which has a special object named `prototype` attached to it. Every instance of the class has an internal link to the prototype of the constructor.

Comment: So I am understanding that my version is syntactic sugar over Leetcode's template. If I used a class - what is it called, what Leetcode did? Function expression? Object constructor?

Comment: I don't know if leetcode supports ECMAScript2015 (also known as ES6) but if it does the behavior should be the same because it will test your code by calling `new MapSum(...)` then calling the methods on the instance.

Comment: The two syntaxes are [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), your version is just a modern syntax.